# how to get the sum of data numbers inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sum, vite

I am currently studying Vue and creating a personal account for the gazoline company.

I have an [API IMG in console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUlBo.png)
inside the `data` array there is also a `transfer` array, also u can see in below picture.

[image]

This data is output like this **:**

[image]

I want to get the amount of income in each `tankfarme`. How can I do it ?

somehow I was able to get the amount of the expense, but it receives the entire amount, and not in one tankfarm. Here is code

```
const getSumExpense = computed(() => {
 let array = getTransfers.value.transfers.data;
 let sum = 0;
 array.forEach((element) => {
 let arrayIncome = element.transfer;

 arrayIncome.forEach((el) => {
  sum = sum + el.expense;
  });
 });

return sum;
});
```

please help me, if you do not understand what I wrote, also tell me, I will try to write better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code:

```js
const arrayIncome = [{expense: 20}, {expense: 30}, {expense: 40}]

const sum = arrayIncome.reduce((a, { expense: e }) => a + e, 0)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the sum of some specific **tankfarm** then you have to filter the array first and then with the help of `reduce` you can sum the records.

```js
const data= [{tankfarm: 'cymma', transfer: [{expense: 10}, {expense: 20}]}]
const result = data.filter(element => element.tankfarm === 'cymma')[0].transfer.reduce((a, { expense: e }) => a + e, 0)

console.log("cymma expense", result)
```